# How to connect SSH Key and fix bad configuration option ssh-ed25519?

Tags: github, ssh, ssh-keys

After generating the ssh key, when I push to the remote GitHub server, this is an error message I can see in my terminal:

```sh
/Users/.ssh/config: line 1: Bad configuration option: ssh-ed25519
/Users/.ssh/config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options
```

How to resolve it?

Answer (score 10):

Considering Linux and MacOS OpenSSH implemention can diff, you can follow [this article](https://www.unixtutorial.org/ssh-bad-configuration-option-usekeychain/)

> I got this error when I attempted to use the .ssh/config file from macOS on my laptop with LMDE4:
>
> ```sh
> greys@xps:~ $ ssh mcfly
> /home/greys/.ssh/config: line 14: Bad configuration option: usekeychain
> /home/greys/.ssh/config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options
> ```
>
> Because this option is a generic one I have at the very top of my `.ssh/config` file, it means I can’t connect anywhere until I fix or comment this "`UseKeychain yes`" option.
>
> Luckily, there’s a simple enough fix: just add the `IgnoreUnknown` directive into `.ssh/config` right above the "`UseKeychain yes`", and it will be ignored on Linux systems.
> On macOS it will still keep working as intended.
>
> Here’s how the updated fragment of .ssh/config should look:
>
> ```sh
> IgnoreUnknown UseKeychain
> UseKeychain yes
> ```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you've accidentally placed an SSH public key into `~/.ssh/config`, since `ssh-ed25519` is the first part of a certain type of public key.

If that's the case, you can edit that file and remove the offending line, which should make OpenSSH happy again.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @bk2204 is incorrect. When using a hardware token such as a YubiKey, you use the public key in place of the private key to tell OpenSSH to use the key for authentication. The public key comment on the end should have either the GPG key number, or the token card id to tell OpenSSH where to look for authentication.

The public key will look like:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2E... openpgp:0x3F2F3A7A
```

https://developers.yubico.com/PGP/SSH_authentication/Windows.html